# Drupal Views overflow

Tags: views

I have a Drupal 7 / Views question... I have a site with some data reports displaying in various graphs/ gauges etc. I also have a "Data" page that shows all of the data used so the user can look through it and/or even download it. My problem stems from the views table overflows past the screen on the right with data. This in itself is not a big issue, but I was wondering if there was a way to contain the view inside a fixed size box/container that is scrollable. Much like a text box.

Again, not that it would help the functionality but sure would make it look nice and clean.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are focusing on the problem of data overflow from the views table, CSS could solve the issue.

For example if you write a code similar to this:

```
<style>
  .container
  {
    background: #fee;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    box-orient: vertical;
  }
  .header
  {
    background: #fee;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -moz-box-flex: 0;
    box-flex: 0;
  }
  .footer
  {
    background: #eef;
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    box-flex: 1;
  }
</style>

<div class="container">
  <div class="header">...</div>
  <div class="footer">...</div>
</div>
```

The only factor that is missing and could prevent the overflow is:

```
width: 100%;
```

Often you need to set the height of Content as well. If the height attribute is not set, the div will grow vertically as tall as it needs to. You may also try using a **FixedHeightContainer**

Comment: It figures it would be a CSS solution...would I put this in the style.css file or create another file?